# Three white, two black balls: what are the chances that no black one remains after three draws?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is an easy combinatorics problem but I can never understand when order does or doesn't matter. There are a million examples but none that seem to give me any clue to how to solve exactly this problem.

> We have $5$ balls in total: $3$ white, $2$ black. We draw them blindly one after the other until $3$ have been drawn. What is the probability that no black ball remains?

Working on this problem, I restated it as "What is the chance that we draw two black balls in three attempts?" I found $C(5,3) = 20$ ways to draw $3$ balls altogether from a set of $5$, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do the same for the black balls.

An example I read had $9$ red balls in a set of $20$ or so balls, and $6$ draws. He said that it was $C(9,6)$ ways to draw the reds. That's just false, because that would mean there would be $C(2,3)$ ways for these black balls and what the heck is that? A negative number?

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it will clarify things if you assign names to the balls, as in $\{W_1,W_2,W_3,B_1,B_2\}$.  Now can you enumerate the possible combinations with $2$ black balls?

Comment: @lulu No that doesn't help at all.

Comment: Note that $\binom{5}{3} = \frac{5!}{3!2!} = \frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3!}{3! \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{5 \cdot 4}{2 \cdot 1} = 10$.  Also, $\binom{2}{3} = 0$ since it is not possible to select three objects from a set of two objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the "guy's red ball problem" and yours. In the "red ball problem" he has $9$ balls and he draws $6$ balls. Here $9>6$, so, the answer to the question:

1. *In how many ways can I draw **only** red balls*

is indeed $C(9,6)$. In your case, you have $2$ black balls, but you draw $3$ balls, so here $2<3$, and therefore $C(2,3)$ does not make sense as an answer to the question

2. *In how many ways can I draw **all** black balls*

(of course note that these questions are different in the first place!). So, how to proceed?

The answer is the following: You are going to pick $3$ balls and you want $2$ of them to be black and necessarily $1$ of them to be white. So

- $C(2,2)$ ways to pick the two black balls
- $C(3,1)$ ways to pick one white ball

By the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) (or multiplication principle) multiply these two to get the total number of ways to perform this task. Lastly, the total ways to pick $3$ balls out of $5$ is as you correctly have equal to $C(5,3)$ (which by the way is equal to $10$ and not $20$ as you write), hence giving you a probability of $$\frac{C(2,2)C(3,1)}{C(5,3)}=\frac{3}{10}$$

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as a single draw of $3$ balls, which has the same "effect" as drawing one ball at a time:

- The total number of ways for drawing $3$ out of $5$ balls is $\binom53=10$
- The number of ways which include the $2$ black ones is $\binom31\cdot\binom22=3$
- Hence the probability of drawing the $2$ black ones is $\frac{3}{10}$

Comment: Why C(3,1) and C(2,2)? And why do the laws of combinatorics seem to change with every problem? Why can't I use that guy's red ball solution to this?

Comment: @Yeats: Choose $2$ out of $2$ black balls, and then choose the remaining ball out of the $3$ white balls.

Comment: So you're combining probablity calculations with permutations? Beyond confusing.

Comment: @Yeats It is situation normal, actually.  Combinatorics and Probability go together like bread and sandwich.